# Angularjs Openlayer draw polyline

Tags: angularjs, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

I hope to find a quick answer for my problem.

I am using openlayer directive (https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive) to draw a map in my App.
I would like to add polyline to the map which shows a route on this map.

I could not find any solution for this. Is it possible to draw these lines?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw a line between set of points, first transform each co-ordinate

```
points.push(ol.proj.transform([xx,yy],'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
```

then create LineString Geometry

```
var thing = new ol.geom.LineString(points);
```

and create a feature and add it to a layer

```
var feature = new ol.Feature({
    name: "Thing",
    geometry: thing
    })
});

vectorSource.addFeature( feature );
```

Demo
https://plnkr.co/edit/WqWoFzjQdPDRkAjeXOGn?p=preview